# Android: how to set the height/width of the src image of a ImageButton?

Tags: android, imagebutton

Android: how to set the height/width of the image(src image intead of the background) of a ImageButton?

I want to set the height/width of the top level image(not the background) image, the size of image should be customized instead of fullfill the button automatically

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899088/adjusting-the-size-of-an-imagebutton-in-android

Comment: I want to set the height/width of the top level image(not the background) image, the size of image should be customized instead of fullfill the button automatically.

Answer (score 21):

You can just Use the `scaleType` attribute of `ImageButton`.
Set it to `fitXY` or `fitCenter` or anything else according to your need.

like this

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/some_image">
</ImageButton>
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question is asking for a way to set the size of `android:src` instead of the whole `ImageButton`. E.g. having a `ImageButton` that is 100dp x 100dp with src image at 35dp x 35dp

Answer (score 6):

You can use Bitmap.createScaledBitmap to scale the image to the size you want.

```
Bitmap image = ... //load image from your source
image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, desiredHeight, desiredWidth, true);
```

Comment: According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap) you put the sizes inverted, you need to make like this: `image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, desiredWidth, desiredHeight, true);`

Answer (score 3):

**xml**

```
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/picture_id"
android:layout_width="10dp"  //here width with unit. 5 dp exemple
android:layout_height="3dp"  //here height with unit. 3 dp exemple
android:src="@drawable/picture_name"
/>
```

**EDIT: (java code) based on https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2009/12/25/resizing-a-bitmap/**

```
// load the origial BitMap (500 x 500 px)
    Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
           R.drawable.android);
   
    int width = bitmapOrg.width();
    int height = bitmapOrg.height();
    int newWidth = 200;
    int newHeight = 200;
   
    // calculate the scale - in this case = 0.4f
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
   
    // create a matrix for the manipulation
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // resize the bit map
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    // rotate the Bitmap
    matrix.postRotate(45);

    // recreate the new Bitmap
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, 0, 0,
                      width, height, matrix, true);

    // make a Drawable from Bitmap to allow to set the BitMap
    // to the ImageView, ImageButton or what ever
    BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(resizedBitmap);
   
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
   
    // set the Drawable on the ImageView
    imageView.setImageDrawable(bmd);
 
    // center the Image
    imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);
   
    // add ImageView to the Layout
    linLayout.addView(imageView,
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                  LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT
            )
    );
```

Comment: it just adjust the width and height of the whole button, i want to adjust the src image.

Comment: Thanks, it's a little complicated for me. I turned to use another icon to walk around.

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem... change the size of 'src' image of image button(not the size of button just image only).

what i did--

> I moved those '.png' file from 'drawable' folder to 'drawable-hdpi' folder.

weird... but it worked.

thanks,

Answer (score 3):

> set **padding** and scaletype to **centerInside**

Padding will help you customize the source image to provide the required height and width.

```
 <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/location"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_circle_border"/>
```