# adjust image button's margin,height and width programatically

Tags: android, android-layout

i have an imagebutton and its width and height are specifiedin xml file.but i want to change
this with screen size of devices.
**How can I set an ImageButton's width,height and margin programmatically?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//ImageView Setup
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);

//setting height and width of imageview
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

//setting margins around imageimageview
params.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10); //left, top, right, bottom

//adding attributes to the imageview
imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 5):

Hi friend you can either set by this below code

```
btnPlayVideo.getLayoutParams().height = XX;
btnPlayVideo.getLayoutParams().width = XX;
```

or see this [imageButton resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164415/android-how-to-set-the-height-width-of-the-src-image-of-a-imagebutton)

Answer (score 3):

It can be achieved via both programmatically and via xml

1) Via programmatically it can be trickest one.

```
You can get the width and height of the screen and set one parameter for both 
layout_width and layout_height of button.
```

How??

```
Display display=((WindowManager)getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).
                                      getDefaultDisplay();
    int width=display.getWidth();
    int height=display.getHeight();
```

//Calculate width and height

```
 Say For screen 240*320

 buttonWidth=width/5;     result: buttonWidht=48;
 buttonHeight=height/10   result: buttonHeight=32;
```

Using LayoutParams object, set width and height to the button.

Now, if you run this code on device having screen size 320*480

```
 buttonWidth=width/5;     result: buttonWidht=64;
 buttonHeight=height/10   result: buttonHeight=48;
```

and so on for other devices too.

2) Via Xml you can also acheive this, that will be easier to implement

```
You just need to put your xml file in different folders of res and change the
values of your views accordingly.

Example: if you have main.xml

res>layout>main.xml.
res>layout-small>main.xml
res>layout-large>main.xml
res>layout-xlarge>main.xml

now you just need to change the values of your button's width and height.
in each main.xml
```