# Incorrect overlay behavior in FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html), child views in FrameLayout are drawn on top of each other with the most recently added view on top. I have notice though, that this seems to not be accurate in Lollipop or later. For example, in the following xml, the button is still visible even though it should be covered by my custom view.

It is worth mentioning that although my custom view extends FrameLayout, I do inflate a child view, so my FrameLayout isn't empty.

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/some_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="button"/>

    <mycustomframelayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Button always displays on top in FrameLayout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32307245/button-always-displays-on-top-in-framelayout)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Buttons in Lollipop and higher have a default elevation to them which causes them to always draw on top. You can change this by overriding the default [`StateListAnimator`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/StateListAnimator.html).

Try putting this into your button XML:

```
android:stateListAnimator="@null"
```

The FrameLayout should now cover the button.

Comment: you should be answering [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32307245/button-always-displays-on-top-in-framelayout) as well

Comment: @RahulTiwari Hmm...not sure that is the same issue.

Comment: @Rahul Tiwari Trouble is that the answers provided for that question aren't satisfactory answers.

Comment: that's why I asked @drschultz to write an answer.

Comment: Works perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

Try putting an elevation to the FrameCustom:

```
<mycustomframelayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:elevation="100dp"/>
```

Comment: whats the default button elevation for android ?

Comment: elevation more than 5 is working fine.